# Scanning application for Mac

Tags: osx, pdf, office

I'd like to find a scanning application for Mac OS X which is similar to the Linux application [*Simple Scan*](https://launchpad.net/simple-scan).
Features I'm interested in:

- scan and save multiple pages in one document
- save documents as PDF
- scan images and documents

The current default Mac scanning application, *Image Capture*, cannot save multiple pages documents. I know there's also the possibility of using *Preview* to accomplish this task, but the process is cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image Capture can save multi-page PDFs, I use the feature all the time.

First you'll want to switch form the simple view to the detail view:

[image]

Then select the format you want to save to, and check the "Combine into single document" checkbox.

[image]

Once you set these settings, they will become the default settings until you change them.

Comment: including a link would be good ;)